# Make toggle column subtotals in SSRS behave like pivot table subtotals

Tags: reporting-services, toggle, ssrs-2012, expand

I've set this report up with expandable groups in the same header column and the detail in the data column of the table.

Is there a way to make each header row's subtotal disappear when the next level down is expanded, just like Excel pivot tables do when you click the expand control?

So when 2014 expands to show the months, that overall total against 2014 goes away, when January expands into the territory level that figure goes away and so on?

[image]

My sub totals are just sum's of the data at each level of the grouping like so;

[image]

I guess I'm thinking either cell visibility properties or even setting the font colour with an expression based on whether or not that row is expanded. I just can't figure out if you can write an expression based on something being "toggled on or off" in SSRS.